# How to get R2 of out of sample prediction in F# using R.predict_lm

Tags: r, f#

I have the following code which performs out-of-sample forecast:

```ml
let myannual = Frame.ReadCsv("data/annual.csv") |> Frame.filterRows (fun    _ row -> not(Double.IsNaN row?CRSP_SPvwx))
let myyears = [| for i in myannual.GetColumn<float>("yyyy").Values -> float i |]
let myreturn = [| for i in myannual.GetColumn<float>("CRSP_SPvwx").Values -> float i |] //return excluding dividends
let DY = [| for i in myannual.GetColumn<float>("D12").Values -> float i |] //dividend yield
let PE = [| for i in myannual.GetColumn<float>("E12").Values -> float i |] //EP ratio
let mynewframe = Frame.ofColumns["return"  => Series(myyears, myreturn) ;
                    "DY"  => Series(myyears, DY);
                    "PE"  => Series(myyears, PE);                     
                     ]

let myyearToPredict = 2000.0
let mytrain = 
    mynewframe |> Frame.filterRows (fun year _ -> year < myyearToPredict)
let mytest = 
    mynewframe |> Frame.filterRows (fun year _ -> year >= myyearToPredict)
let mymdl = R.lm("return~DY", mytrain |> R.as_data_frame)
let predictresults=R.predict_lm(mymdl, mytest |> R.as_data_frame).AsNumericMatrix()
R.summary(predictresults)
```

I would like to get the out-of-sample R^2 (strength of my regression) and I tried to get it with R.summary, but this only gives me max and min of my predicted values. Does anybody know how to fix the last line of the above code so that I can get the R^2 of my prediction?

Answer (score 0):

I am unfamiliar with `F#`, but I believe what you may want is to use:

`R.summary(mymdl)$r.squared`